# VueJS in IE 11 - template wrapper for <tr> not working, works in Edge and Chrome

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11

This is using Vue 2.5.16 in IE 11.  Assume a `dataset` array in app.data, the following works fine in Chrome (and the code is simplified):

```
...
<tbody>
<template v-for="(datarow, index) in dataset">
    <tr><td> {{ datarow }} {{ index }} </td></tr>
    <tr v-if="!(index % 50)"><td> -repeating header row- </td></tr>
</template>
</tbody>
...
```

However, in IE 11, it does not work and furthermore there is no line and character number in console error (took me some time to figure out).  It just says in red:

```
[object Error] {description: "'datarow' is undefined" ..
```

It works if I remove the `template` tag and just put the `v-for` repeat in first `tr` and remove the 2nd one.. but I really would like to have the second one.

I assume this is a DOM issue difference in IE 11 and that IE 11 is hoisting the `template` tag outside the table, but don't know IF any non-standard tag will work, or if so which one will work.  How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a render function or a string template.

Comment: Like so: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvjjWy?editors=1010

Comment: Interesting Bert.  I tend to shy from the `render` because it's no longer easily seen as HTML.  String template I do use, but prefer the SFC way for future.  And so you're saying that either of these will bypass the issues that the code is having with IE11?  I'll def. test it.  Of the three ways, string, render and SFC, which is most performant?

Comment: The primary issue is when the template is rendered into the DOM at some point prior to the template being compiled into a render function. If you use something like `template`, which isn't supported in IE, then the typical HTML rendering rules apply and the `template` tag and everything inside it will be rendered *outside* the table. String templates and single file components, however, are never rendered into the DOM and will not be subject to the rules for rendering HTML before they are compiled into render functions.

Comment: Of course, render functions don't have the issue because there is nothing to be compiled. As far as performance is concerned; I don't expect there is a huge difference between any of the approaches. I expect string templates and single file components would have nearly identical performance characteristics. A render function could be better or worse depending on whether you are able to write a better render function that the compiled version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to have multiple `tbody` elements in place vs. `template`.  Multiple `tbody` tags are allowed in IE 11 without IE moving it out of the table and thus making the `tr` tag unaware of the referenced loop variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

There are two possible side-effects of this:

- Your tbody may have been styled by CSS - mine was in bootstrap - so the appearance will be different than expected, normally with extra borders.  You'll need to probably use `!important` or at least your own CSS to overcome this.
- At least for IE 11, load time appeared slower, but I have not tested this.

Resulting code:

```
<table>
<tbody v-for="(datarow, index) in dataset">
    <tr><td> {{ datarow }} {{ index }} </td></tr>
    <tr v-if="!(index % 50)"><td> -repeating header row- </td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <!-- not posted above but I used another template/tr for the case of no records found; substituted with just another tbody -->
</tbody>
</table>
```