# vue frame in IE browser IE browser has bad drawing

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, internet-explorer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/vue/vue.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="statistics">
    <div v-for="(item,index) in topKeyWords" v-if="(index < 5)" :key="index" >
        <template v-for="(val,key,i) in item">
            <td ><img :src="'images/ssht/pm'+(index+1)+'.jpg'"/></td>
            <td class="ssc" v-if="(key.length > 12)" :title="key">{{key.substring(0,10)+"..."}}</td>
            <td class="ssc" v-if="(key.length <= 12)">{{key}}</td>
            <td v-if="(item[key] != undefined && item[key] !=null)">{{item[key]}}</td>
            <td v-if="(item[key] == undefined)">0</td>
            key:{{key}},item:{{item}}
        </template>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var statisticsVue =new Vue({
    el: '#statistics',
    data: function() {
    return {
            topKeyWords:[{平稳: 4}, {测试: 4}, {情况: 1}],
            isLoading: true
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the data is an object list, and I want to the iterator .  I use Chrome Browser and show very good, but the tester will use another browser including IE,

[IE browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eigzZ.png) 
the v-if is not run,
but chrome is ok,

[chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAjiM.png)

Comment: Does using tbody and tr instead of using a template help you to fix the issue? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue. I found some old threads with similar issues.

If you check the source code in the IE browser then you can notice that it is not showing the **td** tags in code. whereas your actual code contains the **td** tags. Other browsers also show it so this caused the said issue in the IE browser.

Some suggestions in old threads said that you can try to use **tbody** and **tr** instead of using a template. So you can try to make a test with it.

sample code:

```
<table>
<tbody v-for="(datarow, index) in dataset">
    <tr><td> {{ datarow }} {{ index }} </td></tr>
    <tr v-if="!(index % 50)"><td> -repeating header row- </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

References:

1. [<template v-for... not working on IE 10 & 11 on 'table' tag. Woking on other browsers, including IE 9 #3028](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3028)
2. [Custom row templates don't work in IE #138](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/138)
3. [VueJS in IE 11 - template wrapper for  not working, works in Edge and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021827/vuejs-in-ie-11-template-wrapper-for-tr-not-working-works-in-edge-and-chrome)